# How to deal with "Foreign Key" in microservice architecture?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

Quick question on Foreign key in Microservices. I already tried looking for answer. But, they did not give me the exact answer I was looking for.

Usecase : Every blog post will have many comments. Traditional monolith will have comments table with foreign key to blog post. However in microservice, we will have two services.

Service 1 : Post Microservie with these table fields (PostID, Name, Content)

Service 2 : Comments Microservie with these table fields (CommentID, PostID, Cpmment)

The question is, Do we need "PostID" in service 2 (Comments Microservice) ? I guess the answer is yes, as we need to know which comment belongs to which post. But then, it will create tight coupling? I mean if I delete service 1(Blog post service), it will impact service 2(Comments service) ?

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to use another example I'm more familiar with to explain how I believe most people would do this.

Consider an Order Management System (OMS) and an Inventory Management System (IMS).

When a customer places an order in the company web site, we ask the OMS to create an order entry in the backend (e.g. via an HTTP endpoint).

The OMS system then broadcasts an event e.g. OrderPlaced containing all the details of the customer order. We may have a pub/sub (e.g. Redis), or a queue (e.g. RabbitMQ), or an event stream (e.g. Kafka) where we place the event (although this can be done in many other ways).

The thing is that we have one or more subscribers interested in this event. One of those could be the IMS, which has the responsibility of assigning the best inventory available every time an order is placed.

We can expect that the IMS will keep a copy of the relevant order information it received when it processed the `OrderPlaced` event such that it does not ask every little detail of the order to the OMS all the time. So, if the IMS needed a join with the order, instead of calling an endpoint in the Order API, it would probably just do a join with its local copy of the orders table.

Say now that our customer called to cancel her order. A customer service representative then cancelled it in the OMS Web User Interface. At that point an event `OrderCanceled` is broadcast. Guess who is listening for that event? Correct, the IMS receives notification and acts accordingly reversing the inventory assignation and probably even deleting the order record because it is no longer necessary on this domain.

So, as you can see, the best way to do this is by using events and making copies of the relevant details on the other domain.

Since events need time to get broadcast and processed by interested parties, we say that the order data in the IMS is eventually consistent.

**Followup Questions**

*Q: So, if I understood right in microservises we prefer to duplicate data and get better performance? That is the concept? I mean I know the concept is scaling and flexibility but when we must share data we will just duplicate it?*

Not really. That´s definitively not what I meant although it may have sounded like that due to my poor choice of words in the original explanation. It appears to me that at the heart of your question lies a lack of sufficient understanding of the concept of a [bounded context](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html#:%7E:text=Bounded%20Context%20is%20a%20central,being%20explicit%20about%20their%20interrelationships.).

In my explanation I meant to indicate that the OMS has a domain concept known as the order, but so does the IMS. Therefore, they both have an entity within their domain that represents it. There is a good chance that the order entity in the OMS is much richer than the corresponding representation of the same concept in the IMS.

For example, if the system I was describing was not for retail, but for wholesale, then the same concept of a "sales order" in our system corresponds to the concept of a "purchase order" in that of our customers. So you see, the same data, mapped under a different name, simply because under a different bounded context the data may have a different perspective and meaning.

So, this is the realization that a given concept from our model may be represented in multiple bounded contexts, perhaps from a different perspective and names from our [ubiquitous language](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UbiquitousLanguage.html).

Just to give another example, the OMS needs to know about the customer, but the representation of the idea of a customer in the OMS is probably different than the same representation of such a concept or entity in the CRM. In the OMS the customer's name, email, shipping and billing addresses are probably enough representation of this idea, but for the CRM the customer encompasses much more.

Another example: the IMS needs to know the shipping address of the customer to choose the best inventory (e.g. the one in a facility closest to its final destination), but probably does not care much about the billing address. On the other hand, the billing address is fundamental for the Payment Management System (PMS). So, both the IMS and PMS may have a concept of an "order", it is just that it is not exactly the same, neither it has the same meaning or perspective, even if we store the same data.

One final example: the accounting system cares about the inventory for accounting purposes, to be able to tell how much we own, but perhaps accounting does not care about the specific location of the inventory within the warehouse, that's a detail only the IMS cares about.

In conclusion, I would not say this is about "copying data", this is about appropriately representing a fundamental concept within your bounded context and the realization that some concepts from the model may overlap between systems and have different representations, sometimes even under different names and levels of details. That's why I suggested that you investigate the idea of [context mapping](https://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-contextmapping/) some more.

In other words, from my perspective, it would be a mistake to assume that the concept of an "order" only exists in the OMS. I could probably say that the OMS is the master of record of orders and that if something happens to an order we should let other interested systems know about those events since they care about some of that data because those other systems could have mapping concepts related to orders and when reacting to the changes in the master of record, they probably want to change their data as well.

From this point of view, copying some data is a side effect of having a proper design for the bounded context and not a goal in itself.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Well explained! One question though. Does the Order table in IMS, have a foreign key to inventory service? So that when the delete event occurs, we know which inventory is associated with which order? 

In other words, does Order table in IMS hold the ID or the inventory entry?

Comment: The OMS ignores the existence of the IMS, so there is no notion of inventory in the OMS I described above. So the answer is no, but the IMS does know about orders. We say that the IMS is downstream the OMS. At the heart of your problem is the understanding and definition of your domain contexts, right? You may want to learn more about a concept is called [context mapping](https://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-contextmapping/).

Comment: So, if I understood right in microservises we prefer to duplicate data and get better performance? That is the consept? I mean I know the consept is scaling and flexibility but when we must share data we will just duplicate it?

Comment: @Itaywazana I have added a section in the main answer where I attempt to answer your question. Hopefully, I managed to at least point you into the right direction!

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo My question is, does Orders table hold foreign key of Inventory table inside IMS. If order cancellation occurs, we delete the order entry, but also need to update inventory entry in inventory table. So, does orders table hold the ID of Inventory item that order belongs to? Otherwise, how do we know which inventory item to be updated based on cancelled order?

Comment: @rakeshmehra Microservices have their own independent databases, therefore there is no such thing as orders having a foreign key to the inventory or vice-versa.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo But my question remains. If you delete order, how do you know which inventory to be updated? Unless that order holds the ID of a specific inventory? Also, what's the point of having "Relational Database" if there is no relation using foreign key? Thanks!

Comment: @rakeshmehra When I cancel an order, and event OrderCanceled is broadcast. The IMS knows what is inventory assigned to that order and releases it. So the inventory does have a reference to the order it is assigned.

Comment: @rakeshmera I’m getting the impression that you are not fully grasping the concept of microservices. In your example your two services will have completely independent databases. Perhaps one is a relational database and the other in a NoSQL. So there is no such thing as foreing keys between a table in the first service and a document in the second. But obviously this does not prevent the downstream service (e.g. comments) to have a reference id from an entity in the other service (e.g. post id).

Comment: Sry, I am new to Microservices. Final clarification, Let's say 'Post Service(PS)' use MongoDB and 'Comments service(CS)' use RDBMS. Let's say a post is added. PS will create an event. CS will listen to it and it will store post details in it's own 'post' table. Now, every time a comment is added, a row would be created in "Comments" table with a foreign key to posts table(Which is in CS). In case of delete even from from PS, the CS will delete all the comments that corresponds to that post ID. But, I guess no matter what Database we use in each service, the ID of post should remain same.

Comment: @rakeshmehra I would say your last observation is correct.